# Custom Full width Slick-Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to build a special fullwidth carousel with slick : http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/.
In the middle of a Section is the currently shown slide. Left and right you should see a small section of the previous (prev) and next (next) slide.
I have managed to create a version which goes in this direction. But you should see more of the prev and next slider.
Here is a picture of how it should look at the end:
[image]

Example Image 2:
[image]

Here is a CodePen example with my first attempts:
https://codepen.io/Robocop/pen/BpbMKQ

Here is my HTML-Code:

```
    <section class="top_slider">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1300x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1300x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1300x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1300x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1300x300?text=1">
    </div>
</section>
```

Heres is the JS-Code:

```
    $(".top_slider").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    //arrows: false,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" role="button" style="display: block;">Previous</button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" role="button" style="display: block;">Next</button>'
});
```

And finally the CSS-Code:

```
 .slider {
   background-color: white;
   margin: 100px auto;
   height: auto!important;
   }

  .slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
  }

 .slick-slide img {
 width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding: `centerPadding: '220px'` to your slick initialisation. Adjust the number to provide the spacing you want. The higher the padding value, the more of the previous and next images will show.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to achieve this is change

```
slidesToShow: 1,
```

to

```
slidesToShow: 2,
```

in your JavaScript file.

Comment: The Image-Slide in the middle must be a large (almost full-width) image. It is not quite clear in the example picture. The prev and next images must be cropped and displayed. I have done this in my Code-Pen example. But now its not exactly what i want.  From the prev and next picture must be displayed more than now. 
I have uploaded a new image to show what I mean (Example Image 2).

Comment: I have changed the margin-left and margin-right (.slick-slide) but this does not bring the desired success.  
I hope it is now clearer what I would like. Thanks